# Unit testing C Code in Visual Studio 2017 with Native Unit Test Project

Tags: c, visual-studio, unit-testing, embedded, lib

I want to do Unit Tests for a C project in Visul Studio 2017. It is a embedded project lib. I want make as few changes as possible to lib. Just compile c code in VS I have added some #ifdef WIN32. It ok for added some more.

Started with using Visual C++ Native Unit Test Project. But run in problems when wanted test private static functions from C files and inject values varibales in project.

1. Include my embedded project as Static Library in to VS solution. (or should use Dynamic-Link library or something else?)
2. Created Native Unit Test Project, and gave it the name *UnitTest1*.
3. In UnitTest1 added this line as I understand it will include the my lib that want test. 
   `#pragma comment(lib, "../Release/Embedded.lib")`
4. In the embedded code header file I added this Macro to create lib that I will preform the test on.

   ```
   #pragma once
   #ifdef EXPORT_TEST_FUNCTIONS
   #define UNITTEST_Embedded_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
   #else
   #define UNITTEST_Embedded_EXPORT
   #endif

   inline UNITTEST_ZAP_EXPORT static bool isActiv(void);
   ```

   5. In the embedded C file, I added this line `#define EXPORT_TEST_FUNCTIONS` and this function:

   ```
   UNITTEST_ZAP_EXPORT static bool isActiv();
   {
       return false;
   }
   ```
  6. But when I build *UnitTest1* get error LNK2001.

Very unsure how to proceed to make it work. Anyone who can guide me through my problem? I would like to be able to test all functions in C code. Hope it not hard understand what want get help with. I have only developed couple of years.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

I hade same problem as you. You need to explain to the C++ compiler in Visual Studio a C header is coming when you include the declaration for the C function. So your `UnitTest1.cpp` should begins with:

```
extern "C" {
#include "somecode.h"
}
```

`static_lib1.h`should contain something like:

```
 #ifndef STATIC_LIB1_H_
 #define STATIC_LIB1_H_

 SWord doSomeThing();

 #endif
```

Remove everything extra code that have added in your h and c-files for unit test it should not be needed. Best unit test is when don't do any changes to code you test on becouse of unit test need it.

I sure this should fix your problem.